# Multiple Ruby and Rails Versions on OS X Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-yosemite

I'm getting started with Rails development and have a dev environment setup on OS X Yosemite, but the Ruby and Rails versions are a bit wonky. I used homebrew to install Rails, and everything seems to have gone well. Although `which rails` claims it's located in "~/.rbenv/shims/rails", and not /usr/local/bin where homebrew is supposed to place its apps. There's also `/usr/bin/rails` which when run yields:

> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest
>   version, simply type:
>
> ```
> $ sudo gem install rails
> ```
>
> You can then rerun your "rails" command.

`rails --version` returns Rails 4.2.0.

I can create a rails app fine, but when I run `rails server` the ruby version is ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-darwin14.0].

I followed these instructions (mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/ruby-22/) to compile ruby 2.2.0 and `ruby --version` returns "ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]". `which ruby` returns "/usr/local/rbenv/shims/ruby".

Relevant lines in .bash_profile from brew install of Rails and compiled ruby 2.2.0 are:

> if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/openssl/bin:$PATH export
>   MANPATH=/usr/local/openssl/ssl/man:$MANPATH export
>   PATH=/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
>   eval "$(rbenv init -)"

**How do I get the 2.2.0 version of Ruby to run with Rails?** Everything I have read thus far suggests rvm (rvm.io). However, I get homebrew errors when I try to install Ruby that way.

From: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html, section: "If You Already Have RVM Installed"

> $ rvm get stable --autolibs=enable
>   $ rvm install ruby
>   $ rvm --default use ruby-2.2.0

`rvm install ruby` throws the homebrew error.

rvm seems unnecessary considering Ruby 2.2.0 is compiled on my machine already.

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: rvm will make your life easiar when developing rails, b/c you can lock in a ruby version with a set of gems for different rails versions. Can you run `$ brew update` to make sure your homebrew is up to date, then try agian.

Comment: @peterept is right.  Running RoR without RVM is just asking for trouble, trust me.

Comment: I'm not a massive `rvm` fan. My solution is via homebrew: install `ruby-build` and use it to install any/all ruby versions desired, then use `chruby` to switch between them in Terminal. You can also put `.ruby-version` files in your Rails app's root to automatically choose the desired ruby version. As a bonus you also then don't need to type `sudo` before installing gems.

Comment: I too have found `rvm` a bit too heavy and intrusive as well.  I've really liked `rbenv` which it seems you have installed at some point.  Easiest is to probably install rbenv and ruby-build via homebrew (and add the shims to your bashrc like it says in the README) then use the `rbenv install 2.2.0` command to install Ruby 2.2.0 (note that rbenv is incompatible with rvm and you'll want to remove rvm completely).  https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x